# DateTimeFormatter exception

Tags: java

I am having issues with the DateTimeFormatter in Java.

I have the following code:

```
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
LocalDateTime startDate = LocalDateTime.now();
LocalDateTime endDate = LocalDateTime.parse(ceremonyDetails.getDate(), format);
System.out.println(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startDate, endDate)); format);
```

Which should print days between now and date from string, of format 'dd/MM/yyyy', such as '29/09/2016'.

However, I am getting this error:

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '29/09/2016' could not
>   be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor:
>   {},ISO resolved to 2016-09-29 of type java.time.format.Parsed] with
>   root cause java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalTime
>   from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 2016-09-29 of type
>   java.time.format.Parsed

What am I  missing?

Comment: I don know how you add this date, is it in code, maybe you should escape the / ?

Comment: @BertVerhees, in my debugger, date is exactly '29/09/2016'

Comment: @ScaryWombat, I just got that. That was the issue :)

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) rather than [`LocalDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html). One is for a date-only value, the other for a date with time-of-day value.

```
LocalDate.parse( "29/09/2016" , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy") )
```

See examples on the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class documentation page.